# Elephant are less fussy than caterpillars

Tags: word-meaning

Does it mean like this

That elephant are fussy more than the caterpillars (or) caterpillars are more fussy than the elephant

Comment: Just a couple of things to help you with your interpretations: Speaking in general with plural nouns we don't use 'the', so 'elephants' and 'caterpillars'. Also, it's more natural to say 'fussier' when we compare two things.

Comment: Thank you correcting me.

Comment: What a strange comparison.

Comment: I was watching our planets, forest, in it I saw the comparison

Comment: Additionally, it must be about their eating habits. It would make more sense to say: "Elephants are less fussy eaters than caterpillars." or "Elephants are less fussy about food (what they eat) than caterpillars."

Comment: or: "Elephants are less fussy than caterpillars when it comes to eating." In other terms: "Caterpillars are fussier than elephants when it comes to eating." Of course, there might be context that is not provided in the OP. It could be: "Caterpillars are fussy eaters. Elephant are less fussy than caterpillars."

Comment: I’m sorry for my mistake, I’ll see it to next time

Comment: @Blessie No need to be sorry. Just helping in the comment section.  You can consider updating the question also.

Answer (score 1):

The second interpretation is correct. Caterpillars are more fussy than elephants.